# Episerver - How to show/hide properties in the CMS block editor

Tags: javascript, c#, episerver

I have created a new block which contains a table allowing people to enter fields they want to appear in the view. They select the type while they do this and one of the types in 'DropDown'. While entering what fields they would like they also have the option to add select options. I only want the select options part to appear when they have select the type 'DropDown'. The documentation around this on the Episerver site is not great and only mentions how to edit out the box blocks not custom built ones.

[image]

So when field type is anything other than 'DropDown' I do not want the 'Select Options' part to appear. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: I think you will need to add some scripts to your block to hide/show elements based on your needs.

Comment: Anymore information?

Comment: You're going to have to create a custom editor (Dojo widget) to accomplish that in the Episerver UI.

Comment: @JamesBlackburn I guess Ted Nyberg has pointed out the process. otherwise maybe here is valid https://world.episerver.com/documentation/developer-guides/CMS/editing/Creating-an-editor-widget/. I am kind of obsolete with Episerver new versions. The last time I used was version 6 and there we used custom properties to custom ui of editorial properties

Comment: Thanks guys looks like that its the solution. Cannot believe how overly complicated they have made it. What it does is simple at the end of the day! Surely Epi can figure out a much easier and better way to do this! Not going to implement it now just going to tell the content guys only to use it when adding drop downs